# iOS favicons (Add to Home Screen)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, xpages, xpages-extlib

I am using ExtLib and have an app that uses Bootstrap. I would like to add an favicon when the user selects "Add to Home Screen". I have managed to add my icon to the tab bar in Chrome (on the Mac) by extending the bootstrap theme like this:

```
<control override="false">
    <name>ViewRoot</name>
    <property>
        <name>pageIcon</name>
        <value>/$icon</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>pageTitle</name>
        <value>#{database.title}</value>
    </property>
</control>
```

I would now like to add the icons for the "Add to Home Screen" function in iOS. What I need to do is add the following code:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="icon-60x60.png"/>
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="icon-72x72.png"/>
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="icon-114x114.png"/>
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="icon-120x120.png"/>
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="icon-120x120.png"/>  
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="icon-120x120.png"/>
```

to . I just cannot seem to find an example using XPages, ExtLib and the bootstrap theme.

I would love to be able to either add the code to the theme or my layout custom control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use headTag on your layout custom control. Here's an example:

```
<xp:this.resources>
    <xp:headTag tagName="link">
        <xp:this.attributes>
            <xp:parameter name="rel" value="apple-touch-icon"></xp:parameter>
            <xp:parameter name="size" value="60x60"></xp:parameter>
            <xp:parameter name="href" value="icon-60x60.png"></xp:parameter>
        </xp:this.attributes>
    </xp:headTag>
</xp:this.resources>
```

Comment: Thank you Per, this solved my problem of adding to the <head>, unfortunately it did not solve my problem as the GET for the icon is using the base URL and not the Domino URL as setup on the server with a Internet Site document - I'm still trying to figure out why.

Comment: Sounds interesting. Feel free to ask a question on that :-)

Comment: Per, just another question - I tried adding all the resources that are available from the front end before asking my question - how did you know about the <xp:headTag> tag? It comes up as Generic Head Resource... in the frontend and is not editable?

Comment: I don't know where I read about it first but Chris Toohey and others have blogged about it

Comment: I will be in the office tomorrow (only go in about once every 2 weeks :o) but if it does not work internally (i.e. without the reverse proxy involved) I'll post the code on StackOverflow, maybe somebody can help.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you would want to put it in your theme? I want them to bookmark the "entry" page of the application and as such this is where I need the right icons (and I normally put them in a layout custom control anyway).

On the "entry" page of the (typically, single page application) I add something like this to the beginning of the `<head>` tag:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=0">
<meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">

<!-- Fav and touch icons -->
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="images/apple-touch-icon-144x144-precomposed.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="images/apple-touch-icon-114x114-precomposed.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72"   href="images/apple-touch-icon-72x72-precomposed.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon"                 href="images/apple-touch-icon-57x57-precomposed.png">
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png"   href="images/FavIcon.png">
<link rel="icon"             sizes="192x192" href="images/apple-touch-icon-144x144-precomposed.png">
<link rel="icon"             sizes="128x128" href="images/apple-touch-icon-114x114-precomposed.png">
```

You can of course use the headTag as Per Henrik described in his answer if you want to add it to the theme.

And then I also use this little script to [Add-to-Homepage](http://cubiq.org/add-to-home-screen) - on the entry page :-)

/John

Comment: John, the reason for putting it in the theme is that the XPages are less cluttered. I had found the code you mentioned but my problem was/is that I do not have a <head> tag on the XPage so did not know where to place it? My XPage starts with <xp:view> and then has a <xp:panel>. Using Per's example adds the code at the correct place - my problem is still not solved - we are looking into the reverse proxy (somehow the settings in the internet site document get lost i.e. the path to the DB is not appended to the GET when the iPad requests the icon).